# How to get local date time in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way to get local date time stamp in Inno Setup ?

Answer (score 24):

**The answer depends on when you need it.**

- Needed at the time the setup is built
- Needed at the time of install.

**Needed at the time the setup is built.**

You will need to use [ISPP](http://ispp.sourceforge.net/) which is part of the [Quick Start pack](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php).

You can use the `str GetDateTimeString(str, str, str)` function.

Example:  `#define MyDateTimeString GetDateTimeString('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss', '-', ':');`

The help menu in [ISTool](http://www.istool.org/) (Also a part of the Quick Start Pack) has a good help file for ISPP functions including this one where there is a page of information on this function.

**Needed at the time of install.**

Although a different source, the function is also called `GetDateTimeString`
Then it must be in a pascal coding block.

Example:

```
function DateTime : String;
begin
  result := GetDateTimeString('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss', '-', ':');
end;
```

The details of how to use it are found in the [Help File](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getdatetimestring.htm).

Although both functions have the same name, the context of when they are used is important to understanding why you would get one value over another.

Comment: are you sure?  `FormatDateTime` gives a compile error for me (I had to write my own).

Comment: I am now struggling to find out where I found this list.   A simple scripting test, shows that TDateTime is not a supported type in InnoSetup Pascal Script.   I will research options and update the answer.

Comment: The function needs a dummy string parameter, e.g.
`function DateTime(dummy: String): String;`

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code:

```
function ActualDate(Param: string): String;
begin
   result := GetDateTimeString('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss', '-', ':');
end;
```