# How do you add installation related computed strings to InnoSetup scripts?

Tags: date, version, inno-setup, computed-values

Currently when I upgrade a program I backup the existing files to a folder named backup in the program directory eg .

```
Source: "{app}\filename.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\backup"; Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```

Is there a way to specify or compute a strings so the code is something like

```
Source: "{app}\filename.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\backup{date}"; Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```

or combine a date with info on the previous version

```
Source: "{app}\filename.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\backup{previous version}{date}"; Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```

Comment: See [this article](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Backup_of_application_directory) for an example.

Comment: @Deanna, +1. very nice example. maybe you should post that code as an answer (not sure). a side comment, I think that a backup to "{app}" directory is a very bad idea (specially if it's in the Program Files). "Common App Data" or even the "Temp" folder is a better idea.

Comment: @kobik: Posted. I don't use or condone it, but some people want and think they require it :)

Comment: I have realized that saving information to Program Files is a bad idea after Vista and Windows 7. I get away with it on Windows XP but that is going to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read [Pascal Scripting: Scripted Constants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptconstants.htm) and [Pascal Scripting: Support Functions Reference](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptfunctions.htm). Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151972/how-to-get-local-datetime-in-innosetup) and [this](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Backup_of_application_directory).
Anyway, this is how I did it:

```
[Dirs]
; create an empty folder...
Name: "{app}\{code:MyDateTimeString}"

[Code]
function MyDateTimeString(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := GetDateTimeString('yyyy.mm.dd_hh.nn.ss', #0, #0);
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add runtime dynamic values using [`{code:...}` constants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptconstants.htm).

An example of getting the current date and making a backup of the installation folder can be seen on the [ISXKB wiki](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Backup_of_application_directory)

Comment: I had to award @Gregory because he responded first. Only 35 points, really an SO newbie!!

Comment: Check your times :) But yes, I tend to vote up the more fuller answers and newer users too.

Comment: I am into inno-setup most of my time these days, since I am moving away from NSIS and going towards INNO fast! Thus, I was able to help with this one and also help myself, that was trying something similar. I guess this is why StackOverflow is so great; in concept and implementation! Greets to all (and try to chill out with that voting thing! LOL)